# Error encountered running simple cgo file

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to test cgo code.

```
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>

import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("test %d\n", int(C.random()))
}

D:\Dev\Go\src>go version 
go version go1.3 windows/amd64

D:\Dev\Go\src>go env 
set GOARCH=amd64 
set GOBIN= 
set GOCHAR=6 
set GOEXE=.exe 
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64 
set GOHOSTOS=windows 
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=D:\\Dev\\Go 
set GORACE= 
set GOROOT=c:\go 
set GOTOOLDIR=c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64 
set CC=gcc 
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64-mthreads -fmessage-length=0 
set CXX=g++ 
set CGO_ENABLED=1

D:\Dev\Go\src>go run test_binding.go
# runtime/cgo C:\Users\hyoon\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build779392087\runtime\cgo\_obj\_cgo_defun.c:7 6c: No such file  or directory: runtime.h
```

please check the last error. what's wrong?

Comment: Seems like a broken install, can you try with Go 1.4?

Comment: @OneOfOne: What output did you get when you ran the program?

Comment: @peterSO after switching to `/* xxx */` comment style and `import "C"` on a separate line, it printed a random value for me. `test 1804289383`

Comment: The "special" comments must **immediately** precede the import statement, your example has a blank line and so I get "`could not determine kind of name for C.random`"). (Just like godoc comments they must not have blank lines before what they document.) See first few paragraphs of `godoc cgo`. As you've also discovered, but is less clear from the documentation, `import "C"` seems to have to appear by itself separate from the regular `import ( … )` block.

Comment: @OneOfOne + all thanks! upgraded to 1.4 and removed empty line as you said, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What output do you get from this program?

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("test %d\n", int(C.rand()))
}
```